# How to determine where focus went after my TextField lost focus (Android Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, uitextfield, focus, android-jetpack-compose

When my `TextField` lost focus how can I determine where focus went?

```kotlin
var input1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var input2 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

Column{
    TextField(
        value = input1,
        onValueChange = {input1=it},
        Modifier.width(150.dp).onFocusChanged { state ->
            if (state == FocusState.Inactive){
                // Here I know that Input1 lost focus but how can I determine for sure the focus went to other then Input2 UI element?
                if (focusWentNotToInput2){
                       // Do semething
                }
            }
        }
    )
    TextField(
        value = input2,
        onValueChange = {input2=it},
        Modifier.width(150.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't matter. My TextField1 lost focus and I have to do something if focus went to some other ui element then TextField2

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution for this but not like it 100%. At least it works.
I am setting a flag if input2 is focused then if input1 loses focus I wait for 50ms and if `isInput2Focused` flag is not triggered then some other ui element is focused

```kotlin
var isInput2Focused by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

var input1 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
var input2 by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Column{
    TextField(
        value = input1,
        onValueChange = {input1=it},
        Modifier.width(150.dp).onFocusChanged { state ->
            if (state.isFocused) isInput2Focused = false
            else{
                coroutineScope.launch {
                  delay(50)
                  if (!isInput2Focused){
                       // Do semething
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    )
    TextField(
        value = input2,
        onValueChange = {input2=it},
        Modifier.width(150.dp).onFocusChanged { state ->
            if (state.isFocused) isInput2Focused = true
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a proper work around with the problem. It's not that much fine looking although it worked.
I just used two variable to determine when textfiel lost focus

```
//two types of validattion is there
val isPasswordError = validationErrors.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()

//weather is focus or not
var passwordDoneClick by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

// wather focus gone
var ispasswordFocusedGone by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

.onFocusChanged {

                            if (it.isFocused){
                                passwordDoneClick = true
                                ispasswordFocusedGone = false
                            }
                            
                            if (passwordDoneClick && !it.isFocused){
                                ispasswordFocusedGone =true
                            }
}
//error to show in ui

            if (isPasswordError && ispasswordFocusedGone ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Password is invalid",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                    color = Color.Red
                )
                Spacer(modifier = modifier.height(8.dp))
            } else {
                Spacer(modifier = modifier.height(8.dp))
            }
```