# Jetpack Compose TextField blur event

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm implementing form controls, with validations etc. I want an error message to be shown only when a user "blurs" the TextField, in other words, when the field loses its focus. In Angular, we have [touched](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#:%7E:text=When%20the%20user%20blurs%20the%20form%20control%20element%2C%20the%20control%20is%20marked%20as%20%22touched%22.) state that we can proceed from. How to listen for losing focus state in Jetpack Compose?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Screen() {
  TextField(
    onBlur = {
      // P.S. This parameter does not exist
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: related but a bit hacky: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806874/how-to-determine-where-focus-went-after-my-textfield-lost-focus-android-jetpack

Answer (score 4):

You can use **onFocusChanged**.

Sample Code:

```
var color by remember { mutableStateOf(Black) }
Box(
    Modifier
        .border(2.dp, color)
        // The onFocusChanged should be added BEFORE the focusable that is being observed.
        .onFocusChanged { color = if (it.isFocused) Green else Black }
        .focusable()
)
```

Update Answer:

TextField API update - merged onFocus and onBlur callbacks into a single onFocusChange(Boolean) callback with parameter

Source: Version 0.1.0-dev15 - July 22, 2020

Comment: Your approach has one drawback: onFocusChanged invokes immediately. onBlur is more about "lazy" invocation (after focus but not before). You can check it by setting else color to Red, it will be Red on start. Like however.

Comment: my Update answer

Comment: Still don't understand what I have to do

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this issue, I solved this using @snorlax answer, but improving on it. My problem was a `TextField` data validation. The `TextField` is by nature focusable, different from a `Box`, so adding `.focusable()` after defining the event was not doing what I planned: the validation happened once the component appeared on screen, and obviously we didn't want that.

On the `.onFocusChanged` modifier, we can check the event types and use it to change the blurred state, triggering then the validation.
I had a `validate()` function and a `validState` boolean state that I used between my presenter and my view, but I'll make it simple here and you may ignore the implementation of the state class:
We have the focus events, and we can emulate a blur event with a simple flag:

```
class FieldValidState {
    var value: Boolean by mutableStateOf(true)
}

@Composable
fun TextFieldValidation(validState: FieldValidState = remember { FieldValidState() })
    Column {
        var isBlurred = false 
        TextField(
            Modifier
                .onFocusChanged { 
                        if (!it.isFocused && isBlurred) validState.value = validate()
                        if (it.isFocused && !isBlurred) isBlurred = true }
        )
    }
}
```

So what happens here is: I want the validation function to be triggered after lost focus on the `TextField`. On startup, the field is inactive (i.e. `it.isFocused == false`) but I don't want to validate then. So once the focus is on the field and it was not blurred before, `isBlurred` becomes true and when it loses focus, it will be validated.

Let me know if this helps! Thanks!